# botui.action.select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Fala galera, beleza?

Preciso de um help aqui em vuejs, mas precisamente na API botUI.

Tenho o seguinte action do select:

```
const response = await this.instance.action.select({
      action:
        {
          placeholder: question.content,
          multipleselect: question.multipleselect,
          options: question.options.map(options => {
            return {value: options.value, text: options.text}
          }),
          button: {
           label: 'Enviar'
          },
        },
    })
```

Preciso colocar um botão além do enviar, com um outro tipo de ação (voltar para perguntar anterior), no momento estou utilizando async e await, por isso optei não usar then().

Agradeço.

Gabriel Barreto